# Execute a code block in a map in Python

Tags: python

I want to replicate the following JavaScript code in Python:

```
let a = [0, 4, 5]
b = a.map(x => {
  if(x < 3) return 0
  else return 1
})
```

Any idea how I can do this?
I'm not sure how execute a code block in a `map` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can either make a function, or use a lambda function like this:

```
>>> a = [0, 4, 5]
>>> b = map(lambda x: 0 if x < 3 else 1, a)
>>> b
[0, 1, 1]
```

The only kind of anonymous functions in Python are lambdas, and they're limited to being only an expression, if you want a proper function you have to give it a name:

```
def map_f(x):
    if x < 3:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

b = map(map_f, a)
```

Comment: ya python goes out of its way to make normal functional operations `filter` `map` `fold` `reduce` etc unwieldy

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer list comprehension to the `map` function.

```
>>> a = [0, 4, 5]
>>> [int(x >= 3) for x in a]
[0, 1, 1]
```

They allow you to use whatever expression you want without having to create a function.